# Export sheet to XLS without copying VBA - have existing code using copy, need help copying by range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a "main" workbook that has several tabs for several different order processing tasks. I past data, run some macros that format or add columns based on values. Then I export the current worksheet to  new predefined XLS file named based on cell value variables. E.g. - there's a "setting" sheet that contains the path and filename of the exported sheet.

I've been using the following code which was based on someone's forum post, slightly modified. It uses the old file save method (which sometimes crashes randomly), yes I know, but I don't know how to write newer code.

The problem is that these sheets show a user form on active that has buttons to do the tasks. When the sheet is exported to the new XLS it's done by the copy sheet method, which carries over the VBA "worksheet.activate" code. When the new book opens it tries to run the userform which doesn't exist.

I found code that tried to delete the VBA here and on other forums, and I enabled the trusted VBA model option in the trust center, but it doesn't work. So, basically, I need help with finding a way to export the sheet's active ranges (there are no blank lines) to the new XLS file (which gets overwritten every day so technically it's not a "new file") using the cell values, not the worksheet.copy method.

```
Public Sub PrintExport()
Dim rng As Range
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim EXPath As String

EXPath = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Settings").Range("B2")

Range("A2").Select
    If Range("A2") = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Not enough data.")
Exit Sub
Else

Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=EXPath, filefilter:="xls Files (*.xls),*.xls,")


        'Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="xls Files (*.xls), *.xls")
        If fileSaveName <> False Then

            ActiveSheet.Copy
            Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook
            Set sht = wkb.ActiveSheet
            ActiveSheet.Name = "sheet1"
            sht.Cells.Delete
            rng.Copy sht.Range("A1")
          'this is where I tried the VBA delete code
            wkb.SaveAs fileSaveName, FileFormat:=xlExcel8
            wkb.Close
        End If
    End If
End If
```

I tried this VBA delete code but no luck.

```
    With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(strName).CodeModule

                        .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines
```

Comment: Have you trusted the VBA project object model?

Comment: The easiest way to remove VBA code from an Excel file is saving it as `.xlsx`.

Comment: Saving .xlsx is -the- option to remove VBA as @Ralph already said, but that is only if you are able to leave the .xls format. Your question does not indicate if that is the case. Please elaborate on the option to change from .xls (binary) to .xlsx (OpenXML without macros). If you support older Office versions that might be an issue, although for most relative current Office versions there are options to read/write the current Office formats.

Comment: @MaartenvanStam I never said that you would have to keep the `.xlsx` format. One could simply save it as `.xlsx` to remove the VBA code and then save it again as `.xls`. All you need is Office 2007+.

Comment: Exactly @ralph, that is why I asked the OP to indicate what his targeted Office versions are. If he is still on Office 2003- converting would be a challenge ;-) You wouldn't want to be on 2003- but you'd be surprised how many still are ... In general your idea is the best if the versions used allow it.

Comment: Current version is 2007-2010. I'm afraid most of your questions are already answered in my OP. The code is saving as XLS, so no macro enabled there, and yes, VBA model already trusted.

Comment: Have you considered using [Power Query] (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-data-from-external-data-sources-Power-Query-be4330b3-5356-486c-a168-b68e9e616f5a) for this task instead?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the "A2" range you are referring to is on the "Settings" sheet you can bypass selecting it first by just referencing it like:

If Sheets("Settings").Range("A2") = "" Then
MsgBox ("Not enough data.")
Exit Sub
Else

Also, not sure why you are using
fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename
when I'm assuming you want the file to be named as defined above in the EXPath string. Knowing that your workbook has more than one worksheet I would cycle through all worksheets to remove all vba code, external links, hyperlinks and formulas. (Make adjustments here as necessary).

```
Dim EXPath As String
Dim nr As Name ' use this if you want to delete named ranges
Dim ws As Worksheet

EXPath = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Range("F4") "set saved file name

    Sheets(Array("Settings")).Copy 'setup array of sheets w just the one sheet
On Error GoTo 0

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Cells.Copy
        ws.[A1].PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
        ws.Cells.Hyperlinks.Delete
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Cells(1, 1).Select
        ws.Activate
    Next ws
    Cells(1, 1).Select

     'Remove named ranges
    For Each nr In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        nr.Delete
    Next nr

     'Get rid of images,shapes w code
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.SelectAll
    Selection.Delete

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & EXPath & ".xlsx" 'modify this line
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
```

Comment: The settings sheet has several of these like below with the full path and file name. Cell A2 is just a descriptor of the item, and B2 is the actual full file path. 
A2: "file1 TEMP IO Exp Path"
 B2: C:\Users\User\Desktop\Temp Shipping\TEMPfile1.xls
(they're not this vague in the actual sheet, just changing "names" to protect the innocent. hah)

each sheet has it's own userform buttons to do different things since each sheet varies slightly, so I woulnd't need to do "next sheet" etc

Comment: You will find out that if you don't cycle through all the sheets in the current workbook there will still be vba (phantom) code in the sheet you are trying to save to and if you don't delete the buttons (shapes) all code attached to those buttons will be saved with that saved sheet.

Comment: I was able to test the code and made a few adjustments.

It was always only saving the setting worksheet, so I'll have to duplicate the code for each sheet with the name set there I suppose. 

Also, it wasn't renaming the new workbook sheet back to "sheet1" (this is a requirement of the next step in the process which another program reads the data in the file, locks it, then adds some tracking info.

I had to guess where to put the rename sheet code, in one of the places it caused Excel to do a full on crash, not sure what the deal is with renaming sheets and causing Excel to do a full stop.

Comment: Also, part of the reason for having the save prompt is to confirm that you want to overwrite (just in case). This method immediately overwrites.

Hmm, in addition, the code to check whether the first cell is empty and halt is gone - that's what the if A2 value was blank = then msgbox "no data" and stops.

Comment: Also want to say thank you for everyone's input at this point.

Comment: Ignore my concern about always only saving the settings worksheet - you wouldn't know what the other sheet names were called and m original code was static for each worksheet .duh...

Comment: Just realized that the ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & EXPath & ".xlsx" won't work - I need the output file format in xlExcel8 (.XLS) since the program that reads the file is older. I tried to do the "FileFormat:=" but that isn't allowed with savecopyas.

Comment: What happens when you change the ".xlsx" to ".xls"  in the savecopyas code?